# RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.IsMetric always return true in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows, region

I'm trying to check if current device culture use km or miles unit, based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020359/units-of-distance-for-the-current-cultureinfo-in-net#) i used RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.IsMetric but it always return True (Tryed on en_GB and fr_FR). There is another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns true for `en_GB` because the United Kingdom [is officially moving to the metric system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrication_in_the_United_Kingdom).

If you want to create your own rules, you can build upon an existing culture, as outlined in an earlier answer: [Create custom culture in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304507/create-custom-culture-in-asp-net)